# Can I conquer anywhere if I have no pieces left on the board?

Tags: small-world

I came across the following scenario this weekend:

Suppose, in a single turn, all of a player's remaining elves are wiped off the board and returned to his hand, leaving him without any elves in play. On his next turn can he start from anywhere (that would be a legal starting territory), since he has no adjacent territories to attack?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely, [the rulebook](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_2015_en.pdf) (on page 4) under the section on Enemy Loss & Withdrawals explicitly covers this:

> If all of a player's Regions were attacked this turn, leaving him with some Race tokens in hand but none on the board, he may redeploy these as if he was doing a First Conquest, on his next turn.

As stated in the other answer, you can also voluntarily withdraw troops from some or all regions.

Answer (score 12):

Yes - but you can also do this every go anyway. You simply need to abandon all regions when starting your turn.

> Abandoning a Region
>
> If the player chooses to abandon all the Regions he previously occupied, his next conquest must follow the same rules as its First Conquest (see First Conquest, p. 4).

http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_2015_en.pdf

Comment: Oh wow, i did not know that. I thought minimum was 1 per area. Learned something new again!

Comment: The minimum 1 token per area rules only is in play at the end of your turn: it is allowed to empty regions at the beginning of your turn (when you gather your troops for attacking) but it's not allowed during the redeployment phase.